# Performing operation on a dataframe column through a list RStudio

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in RStudio and I'm facing a problem. I have a dataset called the sensor_data which has sensors S12, S13, S14 (as column names). I want to record values of: S14 - S13, and S13 - S12 (in this fashion only) and include them in my data frame. Below I've mentioned a simple example of the problem below (which is not working) to see how the result would look like. But this doesn't work because [val -1] is not acting like an index.

I can do them individually and then add them to the dataframe but that is a costly operation. Wondering if there is a smarter way to do it through a for loop.

```
P001<- list("S12","S13","S14")
for (val in P001){
  print(sensor_data[[val]] - sensor_data[[val - 1]])
}
```

I follow the logic from Python programming where I can index lists through a for loop but that doesn't seem to be the case in R.

Any sort of help will be useful. Plus if anybody can recommend a good book where I can learn to do such operations then that would be amazing as well.

Comment: Just a minor thing: RStudio is the IDE (Integrated development environment), while the programming language is called `R`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `base::transform` function or `dplyr::mutate`

Using `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)

sensor_data %>%
  mutate(difference1 = s14 - s13,
         difference2 = s13 - s12)
```

If you want to use a for loop over multiple columns, you could do this:

```
newdata <- sensor_data

for (i in 2:ncol(sensor_data)){
  newdata[ncol(sensor_data) + i - 1] <- sensor_data[i] - sensor_data[i - 1]
  colnames(newdata)[ncol(sensor_data) + i - 1] <- 
    paste0(colnames(sensor_data)[i], "-", colnames(sensor_data)[i - 1])
}
```

Though there may be a more easily readable way out there to do it.

Check out: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html and https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html for info on manipulating datasets and iterations.

Comment: While this does the job, is it possible to not do it manually each time? Because P001 is one production line and in the analysis that I'm doing, there are multiple production lines.